# Assortativity of each graph partitions

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I work on graph analysis and notably on partitioning graphs with *Mathematica*:

`g = RandomGraph[WattsStrogatzGraphDistribution[30, 0.1, 3]];`
`FindGraphCommunities[g]`;
`CommunityGraphPlot[g]`

Then I use `GraphAssortativity` function to measure homophily like this:

`N[GraphAssortativity[g,FindGraphCommunities[g]]]`

My question is:  Is it possible to measure assortativity of each subgraph created? and How can I do with my example?

[image: graph blocks]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to avoid any future back and forth about what needs to be done: can you clearly define what kind of assortativity you want?

Comment: @Szabolcs I want to know assortativity (value) for each blocks created by the FindGraphCommunities function so here with my example with 4 blocks I want to have 4 assortativity values

Comment: you mean `GraphAssortativity /@ (Subgraph[g, #] & /@ FindGraphCommunities[g])`?

Comment: Exactly @kglr can I use Labelled function to legend my graph with each value for each blocks?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by *assortativity* here?  What you originally computed and what @kglr is showing you are two entirely different types of assortativities. The former is based on groups you define yourself while the latter is based on vertex degrees.  It is not clear from your post that you are aware of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
g = RandomGraph[WattsStrogatzGraphDistribution[30, 0.1, 3]];

CommunityGraphPlot[g, 
 CommunityLabels -> N[GraphAssortativity /@ (Subgraph[g, #] & /@ FindGraphCommunities[g])]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
CommunityGraphPlot[g, 
 PlotLegends -> N[GraphAssortativity /@ (Subgraph[g, #] & /@ FindGraphCommunities[g])]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note: As noted by Szabolcs in the comments and explained in [GraphAssortativity >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GraphAssortativity.html), `GraphAssortativity[g0]` is computed based on vertex-out-degrees the vertices of `g0`, and `GraphAssortativity[g0, partition]` is computed using the same categorical value for vertices in a subset.

Comment: But this "assortativity" and the "assortativity" that the OP computed originally are different things. I worry that not making this clear will cause a lot of confusion for future readers.

Comment: @kglr reply good of my answer. In fact the first measure of assortativity is a "initial" measure and then I would detailed this measure for each subgraph

Comment: @Szabolcs, i agree. I added a note with a link to docs.